# Android Upload Multiple Images with Text Data

Tags: php, android, mysql

The below code is uploading multiple images to a server and writing their paths and one name to a mysql database as appropriate. I want to be able to write the user inputted image name for each image. Where possible other user inputted data data to the database too. Kindly help. Attached is the snapshot for the xml.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    Bitmap bitmap1;
    boolean check = true;
    Button SelectImageGallery;
    Button SelectImageGallery1;
    Button  UploadImageServer;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView imageView1;
    EditText imageName;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
    String GetImageNameEditText;
    String ImageName = "image_name";
    String ImagePath = "image_path";
    String ImagePath1 = "image_path1";

    String ServerUploadPath ="http://10.0.3.2/multiple/uploadmultiple.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextImageName);
        SelectImageGallery = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect);
        SelectImageGallery1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect1);
        UploadImageServer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        SelectImageGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 1);

            }
        });

        SelectImageGallery1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image2 From Gallery"), 2);

            }
        });

        UploadImageServer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                GetImageNameEditText = imageName.getText().toString();
                ImageUploadToServerFunction();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {
        super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);
        if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (RC == 2 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            try {
                bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 65, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    public String getStringImage1(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 65, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }


    public void ImageUploadToServerFunction(){
        final String imageName = GetImageNameEditText.trim();
        final String imageView = getStringImage(bitmap);
        final String imageView1 = getStringImage1(bitmap1);

        class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Images Are Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {
                super.onPostExecute(string1);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog after done uploading.
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                // Printing uploading success message coming from server on android app.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Setting image as transparent after done uploading.
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();
                HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
                HashMapParams.put(ImageName, imageName);
                HashMapParams.put(ImagePath, imageView);
                HashMapParams.put(ImagePath1, imageView1);
                String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest(ServerUploadPath, HashMapParams);
                return FinalData;
            }
        }
        AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
        AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
    }

    public class ImageProcessClass{
        public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnectionObject ;
                OutputStream OutPutStream;
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriterObject ;
                BufferedReader bufferedReaderObject ;
                int RC ;
                url = new URL(requestURL);
                httpURLConnectionObject = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnectionObject.setReadTimeout(19000);
                httpURLConnectionObject.setConnectTimeout(19000);
                httpURLConnectionObject.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnectionObject.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnectionObject.setDoOutput(true);
                OutPutStream = httpURLConnectionObject.getOutputStream();
                bufferedWriterObject = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(OutPutStream, "UTF-8"));
                bufferedWriterObject.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));
                bufferedWriterObject.flush();
                bufferedWriterObject.close();
                OutPutStream.close();
                RC = httpURLConnectionObject.getResponseCode();
                if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    bufferedReaderObject = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnectionObject.getInputStream()));
                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String RC2;
                    while ((RC2 = bufferedReaderObject.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            StringBuilder stringBuilderObject;
            stringBuilderObject = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {
                if (check)
                    check = false;
                else
                    stringBuilderObject.append("&");
                stringBuilderObject.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                stringBuilderObject.append("=");
                stringBuilderObject.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            return stringBuilderObject.toString();
        }

    }
}
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $image = $_POST['image_path'];
    $image1 = $_POST['image_path1'];
    $name = $_POST['image_name'];
    $name1 = $_POST['image_name1'];

    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','root');
    define('PASS','');
    define('DB','multiple');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect to Server');

    $path = "uploads1/$name.png";
    $path1 = "uploads1/$name1.png";

    $actualpath = "http://10.0.3.2/$path";
    $actualpath1 = "http://10.0.3.2/$path1";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO multiple2 (image1,name1,image2,name2,time) VALUES ('id','$actualpath','$name','$actualpath1','$name1',now())";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        file_put_contents($path1,base64_decode($image1));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: You have tagged the question with PHP . but I am not seeing any PHP code

Comment: Thanks for the concern want to upload the images to a server and write the paths to a database using php mysql

Comment: That's what I am asking.. Where is the PHP code that we should look up to so that we could help you in resolving your issue.

Comment: Php code now attached. Thanks for fol up.

Comment: Your insert query is wrong. Run it in MySQL with dummy data. You will get the errors. you are passing id in insert in values section but not in insert into abc() and use PHP prepared statements.

Comment: Check how to Insert https://www.guru99.com/insert-into.html

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it guys by looping all images in an iterative loop.